# Shortest Path in MS Access Database

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have to make a Database for a German Company and i came across a complex Problem, which i cant solve entirely in SQL, so i cant print it directly in Access.

I need a shortest way Report in MS Access...

For Example, I have one List with Train Stations and one List with direct connections to these Stations:

```
>Table 1                      Table 2
>+--+---------------+-----+   +------+------+
>|ID|Station        |aCity|   |StaID1|StaID2|
>+--+---------------+-----+   +------+------+
>|01|Dounat Plains  |true |   |    01|    03|
>+--+---------------+-----+   +------+------+
>|02|Vanila Lake    |false|   |    03|    02|
>+--+---------------+-----+   +------+------+
>|03|Spiral Mountain|false|   |    05|    01|
>+--+---------------+-----+   +------+------+
>|04|Gruntys Lair   |false|   |    04|    05|
>+--+---------------+-----+   +------+------+
>|05|New Donk City  |true |   |      |      |
>+--+---------------+-----+   +------+------+
```

Now i have to create something, witch prints every "not City", how its connected with a City and every station it needs to get there.

I think of something Like:

```
>+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+  
>|Station        |Steps                                                | 
>+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+ 
>|Vanila Lake    |Conection over "Spiral Mountain" with "Dounat Plains"|
>+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+ 
>|Spiral Mountain|Conection with "Dounat Plains"                       |
>+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+ 
>|Gruntys Lair   |Conection with "New Donk City"                       | 
>+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

If its more easy: Every City is connected with every other City and every "not City" is only connected to one City but with steps in between.

I thought of something like a Linked List, but i only found how you can use Numbers, where for example you go from 1 to 10 and take 2,3,4,5 etc. as steps, and how you handle them, but never, how you create one, with specific connection like in Table 2.

Now I am stuck, which is not good, because i have to be finished in 7 Weeks and i still have more to do after i finished this Problem.

-**UPDATE**-

I tried some different methods for SQL to solve this Problem and I bet, they would work but Access is just too limited, so my problem doesn't seem to be Managable in MS Access.

But i still need a report with these informations in Access. Is there a Way to write a skript and implementing it in a Access Report?

Comment: so there is only one entry for each stationid in both of the columns `StaID1` and `StaID2`.

Comment: What have you attempted so far yourself? Is this homework / thesis? If so, you should be honest and say so. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: No, im really working for a German Company @Rene, but i couldnt try anything yet, becuase its the most complicated Problem i ever faced and my department isnt used to working with Access. Of course its not about Train Stations IRL, but i cant just give Company informations away. 

I can see, why you would think that, im really new to this but now im on a good way, because of Scorpioo590, who brought me in the right direction.

Comment: @DarkRob In this example, it is that easy, but its oversimplefied for giving a picutre of what im talking about.

Comment: To do this in a SQL query, you need support for hierarchical or recursive queries.  MS Access supports neither of these.

Comment: But access can connect to e.g a SQL-Server(ODBC only for reports if not ADP) and use a recursive query from that (like Gordon suggested) and show the data in an access report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a far from easy to solve problem...

What you are essentially looking for is an algorithm to find (shortest) paths from each nonCity to a city.
This is a graph-problem and as that better to solve with a graph database (e.g. [neo4j](https://neo4j.com))..

Despite this being far from efficient it will not be easy to implement using SQL and I'm not sure if Access-SQL will be able to solve this.

I'd recommend reading up on [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and similar approaches to this problem like this for example: [SQL for shortest path problems](http://aprogrammerwrites.eu/?p=1391#.XUvHwuZR2Uk)

If you can use VBA within your MS-Access application you could try implementing an algorithm as this in VBA instead of SQL.

Comment: Yes, i need the shortest way. I had no Idea, that its a graph Database Problem.
I dont know how to solve it but it has to be in Access. How I solve doesnt matte i think.
Thanks for your Advice. Ill read up on all this.

Comment: TS already has a table with direct connection so none of your links apply. Reading up on your suggestions would be a waste of time.

Comment: He has a list of connections A -> B, B -> C, C -> D and needs to find the path for A -> D
That does kind of look like a shortest-path problem to me?

Comment: @Scorpioo590 your _"SQL for Schortes path"_ Linked helped a lot **BUT** Access denies the _"WITH paths"_ part. I dont know what it causes. If I just delete this part, its complaining about _")SEARH DEPTH..."_

Comment: I fear that might be a limitation of Access that does not support recursive queries...
The `SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY` clause in the example is Oracle-SQL specific and I think there is no equivalent in Access-SQL

Comment: Huh, i geuss my request isnt possible in Access then, isnt it?
I found a entry.
Could http://hansolav.net/blog/ImplementingDijkstrasAlgorithmUsingTSQL.aspx be helpfull? Im trying my best, i hope it works, ill comment here again, if i know more.

Comment: This is T-SQL which Access can not understand.
Do you know if there is a limit of how many stations have to be passed from a nonCity to get to a city? (e.g. something like "a nonCity is at most 3 stations away from the next city")

Comment: No. I just need a conection from every nonCity to a City. Which City it is doesnt matter. Again, every nonCity has only a conection to one of the Citys but not a direct one. Most of them are like Vanila Lake in my Example.

The count of NonCitys to cross can differ and it should be used, so more Citys and NonCitys can be added later, so i dont know if the count of 3 really applies.

Comment: Well you can use Makros in Access, which can be written as a Module, a Classmodule and Visual Basic. Is it possible to solve my Problem that way?

Comment: Yes macros (i.e. VBA) are probably the way to go.
One approach that comes to mind: Use a query to find all NonCites that have a direct connection to a city (let's call these `directNonCitites`). Next use a query to find all NonCities that have a direct connection to a `directNonCity` (let's call these `secondLevelNonCities`). Continue this process until all NonCities are processed.

Comment: This sounds good, but does it list nonCitys, which arent conectet to a City at all too?
Becauese i totally forgot, that thoose have to be showen too, because they have to be conected to Citys at some point.

Comment: In my approach you know you are finished when there are no more NonCities left. This would obviously not work if some NonCities are never processed. Instead you could finish as soon as a turn of the algorithm does not yield any results. At that point all NonCities which have a connection are found. The remaining ones would be those without a connection to a city.

Comment: Keep in mind that vba is slow (e.g single threaded), so a`.Net`library should be prefered, if it is too slow and you don't use a database (Access can connect to any ODBC-Database).

Comment: @ComputerVersteher is it that slow, so it matters? Can i use a .Net without leaving Access anyway? Its more important to keep it simple then letting it run fast.

Comment: Execution time depends on algorithm and amout of data. I've no expirience on that, just start with vba (at least a good exercise) and if it is too slow use SQL-Server via ODBC. [Writing a`.Net`library](https://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html) needs some knowledge on [COM-Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model)

Comment: Access interrogatons? You mean queries? That is impossible as access queries don't know recursion. But you can use SQL-Server for the recursive query and fetch the data with access (pass-through). That has several other benefits (backup, performance, ...), but you need to [migrate the data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/migrate-an-access-database-to-sql-server-7bac0438-498a-4f53-b17b-cc22fc42c979) first

Comment: Sorry, i badly translated it from German. You seem to be German, so ill repeat my Idea in German. 
Ich dachte daran die Abfragen zu nutzen. Ich erstelle erst eine Abfrage für alle "NonCitys" die mit den "Citys" Verbunden sind. Danach eine Abfrage alle, die damit verbunden sind. Das ganze dann 5 Mal. Ausgeben kann ich dann jede Verbindung, die dadurch entsteht. Was sind Abfragen in English eigentlich?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197707/discussion-between-computerversteher-and-cgaguy).